# CSS nth-child(2n) selector selecting all children

Tags: html, css, sass

Here's a fiddle of it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/Chenzorama/gz3hch7s/3/

My simplified HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="top">

<div class="typeone">ONE</div>
<div class="typetwo">Two</div>
<div class="typeone">ONE</div>
<div class="typetwo">Two</div>
<div class="typeone">ONE</div>
<div class="typetwo">Two</div>
<div class="typeone">ONE</div>
<div class="typetwo">Two</div>
<div class="typeone">ONE</div>
<div class="typetwo">Two</div>
<div class="typeone">ONE</div>
<div class="typetwo">Two</div>
<div class="typeone">ONE</div>
<div class="typetwo">Two</div>

</div>
```

I'm essentially trying to apply a style to every other .typetwo div...

I've got some css (well, scss) that should IMO work (by making every other one gray):

```
.top {        
    .typetwo {
         background-color: #0000ff;
        &:nth-child(2n) {
             background-color: #555555;   
        }
    }
 }
```

But when I run this, it turns them all gray. From what I can tell, it's counting ALL the divs inside .top.

Oddly enough, &:nth-child(3n) works correctly? Someone tell me I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change to

```
&:nth-child(4n)
```

because they are all divs (both typeone and typetwo) childrens of the .top div.

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gz3hch7s/4/).

Comment: Right... I had come to that solution (even though it seems... wrong to me.) but does that mean you can't use a class as a selector for nth-child?

Comment: As it says is the nth-CHILD, so it doesn't rely on the class name.

Comment: That's it. Thanks, @florin-pop. I'm not crazy. Just wrong.

Comment: Of course you're not crazy :) I was also surprised when I first found out that.